# Google Chrome does not respond in Remote Desktop session

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop

I login from Windows 7 64-bit to Windows 7 64-bit by Remote Desktop.

I install the latest version of Google Chrome. On start, no add new tab. On close tab, Chrome freezes, not responding. If I minimize and restore Remote Desktop it unfreezes.

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I solved by opening the chrome task manager and killing the GPU process. I guess it can't use the GPU when we're inside an RPD session.